# If "negative" conditions are mentioned in the spec, are such tests still negative?

Tags: testing, theory

In most definitions of negative testing, the idea is that we test outside what is specified/expected and it is highly related to robustness.

So basically, if the behavior for such conditions is defined, I would be positive testing as we verify behavior that is specified, isnt that so?

An example requirement:

> REQ1: Name is a text field with maximal length of 32 chars.

In this case, I could try neative test cases with numbers, special characters etc.

However, what about this:

> REQ1: Name is a text field with maximal length of 32 chars.
>   If a non-alphabetical character is entered, except for a space, a message
>   "Incorrect character entered" is shown.

In this case, I would say that now those tests are positive as I verify the spec.

I ask because I have read the following, in a book Fuzzing for Software security testing:

> in a login feature..a positive tests would consist of trying a valid
>   user name and a valid password. Everything else is negative testing.

That does not seem to be right to me. Usually the behavior for wrong login is pretty well defined and specified so strictly speaking, again I verify described behavior.

Is my understanding correct?

To support the definition I mean, I quote a few books below:

> Positive testing is done to verify known test conditions and negative
>   testing is done to break the product with unknowns.
>
> Another one:
>
> Most systems are designed with explicit and implicit restrictions and
>   constraints. Negative test cases can be derived to test conditions
>   outside of those restrictions and constraints.

Comment: This question might get better answers on our sister site [sqa.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Usually the behavior for wrong login is pretty well defined and
>   specified so strictly speaking, again I verify described behavior.

In well-written software, ideally there should be no user-facing undefined behavior - in practice it is not possible to eliminate it completely (you cannot predict or control everything that could lead to it), but you do your best to get as close as you can. Even when something unpredictable happens, the software should fail gracefully. In that sense, the behavior in all of these scenarios is well-defined, so it's not about that.

It's about whether it's the main/appropriate use-case, where the user acts non-maliciously and performs actions correctly (positive path), *or* an "anomalous" use case - where the user makes an honest error, or is malicious, etc. (negative path).

> Everything else is negative testing, including wrong user name, wrong
>   password,  someone  else’s  password,  and  so  on.

P.S. Wikipedia says: "Negative testing is also known as failure testing or error path testing". The terminology doesn't really matter here, as long as you understand the concept, and test if the system behaves appropriately in these scenarios.

P.P.S. You said:

> If the error/anomalous path is defined in the spec, then it is positive by definition.

The book doesn't define it in that way. Maybe you have some other definition in mind, and that's OK, but that just means that the terminology you are using is not the same as the one used in the book, even if you are using the same words.

> REQ1: Name is a text field with maximal length of 32 chars.
>
> In this case, I could try neative test cases with numbers, special characters etc.

This assumes that by "negative", they mean the opposite of (or otherwise in conflict with) what was specified, but the meaning they use is not about the wording of the specification but about the usage/path (ideal vs anomalous, as described above). I think that's the source of your confusion.

Comment: That does not answer the question, unfortunately. If the error/anomalous path is defined in the spec, then it is positive by definition. I agree it is not possible to fully cover that completely, this is question rather about the nomenclature. As for Wikipedia, that is rather a popular resource, I stick to books.

Comment: @JohnV: OK, maybe we are miscommunicating in some way. Your question is "Is my understanding correct?" - my answer is "No - because your premise is wrong.". Could you expand on what's unclear in my answer? Maybe I can find a way to improve.

Comment: @JohnV: I see you edited your comment above to include more info - I understand now what you mean. "If the error/anomalous path is defined in the spec, then it is positive by definition." - by what definition? The book you are citing clearly doesn't use that definition.

Comment: Not according to this book, but according to most others (and partially also it is a common sense - if that is specified, then I cannot handle it as unexpected and undefined input.

Comment: For example, another book: Most systems are designed with explicit and implicit restrictions and constraints. Negative test cases can be derived to test conditions outside of those restrictions and constraints.

Comment: @JohnV How I interpret that: the restriction being e.g. 32 chars in a field, therefore testing that 33 chars aren't allowed is testing outside the bounds of the constraint, in typical BET testing style. Testing that you get a correct error is still to my mind negative testing, as it's explicitly an error path, even though that error path is defined by the spec.

Comment: @JLewis At first, I thought the same. But more technical books put it that way (and it makes sense): positive test cases are obviously linked to requirements. If that error path is defined, it is a requirement, and thus must be tested to ensure full requirement coverage, meaning it is a positive test.

Comment: @JLewis Just assume this error path is called Requirement XY - then I think it become clear it is not negative testing in terms of trying to break the system but merely verifying compliance to existing and specified behavior. In one book, this is called "negative test condition" for positive testing.

Comment: @JohnV: In that other book you quote, just a few paragraphs above, it says: "There is no universal way to derive negative test cases.", and then it lists different ways to do it - the one you mention is listed under "Known constraints testing", the one the first book is talking about is essentially what this one calls "Use cases and misuse cases". It is not uncommon across different disciplines, and even within subdomains of the same discipline, that people use somewhat different meanings for the same words. This happens even in something as rigorous as math.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Yes, and it quite bothers me, to be honest :) I believe the best explanation I found was the one I mentioned - positive tests are linked to requirements, thus even if its negative in its nature, it is a requirement that needs to be verified during positive testing (i.e. trying to check whether the product does what is is supposed to do).

Comment: The issue is that I don't think that's what is commonly understood when people say positive or negative testing. Whether or not it is correct is likely not something that has a definitive answer

Comment: @JLewis Yes I believe that is the case. For most people, trying to break an input form with special characters is a negative test, even if there is a clear requirement stating specific behavior for this exact case. I guess it is because it is pretty uncommon to cover those cases in specs

Comment: @JohnV: "Yes, and it quite bothers me, to be honest :)" - Yeah, I know how you feel, but it's just something we all have to deal with from time to time. Essentially, the way to avoid confusion (when talking/writing to people) is: define terms up front and get everyone to agree to use them in the same way within your specific context and for the duration of the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You quote a spec:

> REQ1: Name is a text field with maximal length of 32 chars.

where is the rest of the spec? do they want you to truncate it? write it to an error log? play annoying music? note it as a failure? popup a message box?

You mention 32 characters and text. The spec doesn't mention not allowing numbers or special characters, plus the spec should tell you how to handle them.

Once they tell you what to do then you can design the proper test.

The book mentions:

> in a login feature..a positive tests would consist of trying a valid
>   user name and a valid password. Everything else is negative testing.

This assumes that the system specifications has told you how to handle the logins. But that specification has to address how many failures before lockout, are resets by email or security questions allowed, and what the error messages should be. Those specifications are not negative testing. You are expecting a specific behavior.

Comment: But that is exactly my point. In the first case, the requirement is vague, only allowing 32 chars - so negative test cases would be trying numbers etc. However, in the other example, the behavior for such inputs is specified.